# Variable names in plyr summary output and input data frames

Tags: r, plyr

I found a funny feature from `ddply` function. It seems that you cannot use the same variable name in summary output data frame than in input data frame:

```
set.seed(1)
ex <- data.frame(Type = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10)), time = rnorm(20, 6,3))
ddply(ex, .(Type), summarize, time = mean(time), n = length(time))

  Type     time n
1    a 6.396608 1
2    b 6.746535 1
```

`length` comes out as 1. Whereas, if you change the variable name (time) to something else:

```
ddply(ex, .(Type), summarize, tim = mean(time), n = length(time))
  Type      tim  n
1    a 6.396608 10
2    b 6.746535 10
```

It also helps, if I rearrange the columns for the output:

```
ddply(ex, .(Type), summarize, n = length(time), time = mean(time))
  Type  n time
1    a 10 6.396608
2    b 10 6.746535
```

Or rename the variables for the input:

```
set.seed(1)
ex <- data.frame(Type = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10)), tim = rnorm(20, 6,3))
ddply(ex, .(Type), summarize, time = mean(tim), n = length(tim))

  Type     time  n
1    a 6.396608 10
2    b 6.746535 10
```

But:

```
ddply(ex, .(Type), summarize, tim = mean(tim), n = length(tim))

  Type      tim n
1    a 6.396608 1
2    b 6.746535 1
```

I am working on:

```
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
plyr_1.8
```

Is this a known feature of `plyr` or something that has happened after R 3.0.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your first example this is probably because the calculus are made sequentially. First you compute time=mean(time) and thus time as a length one. So after when you ask for length(time) then you get 1 whereas if you ask for the length before creating the object time you get your expected results as demonstrated by your 3rd and 5th examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought that `ddply` would take the vectors from the input data frame. Maybe I was wrong? Your explanation would work if the function would consider the output data frame.

Comment: @Largh I think droopy's explanation is correct, but thanks for pointing this out, I always assumed that it would use the input data frame.